# Updating root filesystem remotely in-place

Tags: linux, chroot, root-filesystem

Let's say one has only remote access (SSH) to an embedded Linux device and the goal is to upgrade the OS to a new version. The device has only one partition, but there's easily more than 50% unused space and the device has about 256 MB of RAM to work with. How would one go about doing that? I'm thinking the solution would probably involve tempfs and pivot_root.

Here's my vague idea for how to do this:

1. upload new rootfs structure to a directory on the device
2. mount a tempfs in RAM and copy over required system resources to keep the system running while the rootfs is being worked on
3. change root to the tempfs using pivot_root or chroot or both, not quite sure
4. copy the rootfs structure from the uploaded directory to replace the old
5. reboot to the new version of the OS

Now, I'm thinking this sounds too simple to actually work. Can you please poke holes in my plan and tell me what I missed or better yet give me pointers to how to do it right? Does anybody have experience in doing something like this?

Comment: What kind of Linux?  Most distributions handle upgrades with something like `apt-get -y dist-upgrade` or similar; is there a reason you can't work *with* rather than *against* your package manager?  ("It's a custom-built system with no package manager" *might* be such a reason, but don't make us guess!)

Comment: It's a custom built system. And built by someone else who didn't consider how to remotely upgrade it later.

Comment: I've had to deal with embedded systems that don't have good provision for upgrades.  If you have dozens/hundreds/thousands of them scattered all over the world, then it's a Hard Problem (sorry).  It gets really trick when you try to ensure that it will always remain bootable, even when you lose power at the wrong moment, or (happened to me once on a local desktop box) run out of disk in the middle of installing the new `libc`.  Without doubt, it's best to have an alternative "rescue" partition containing enough to mount the main root fs and continue the upgrade.

Comment: Sorry if that last comment sounds a bit like, "If you're going there, I wouldn't start from here!"  It wasn't meant to; I'm just suggesting a first priority to get right and the rest should follow.

Comment: I understand that this is not standard procedure and that a power outage in the middle of the upgrade would almost certainly leave the system unbootable. But for someone who knowingly wants to take the risk and do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

chroot will only change the root dir of the current process, so changing the rest of the partition will most probably let the system die (and by that, your current process as well).

The same is true for pivot_root:

> pivot_root moves the root file system **of the current process** to the directory put_old and makes new_root the new root file system.

When I had to update the root filesystem of a raspberry pi, I attached a USB drive to it and booted from there. The temporary file system worked fine and I could change the "real" root file system without ever removing the SD card. (The raspberry  pi was hard to reach, but I was able to insert a USB stick).

I can't think of a proper way to "boot" only into a ram disk, as the **init**ial startup of the system still comes from the media. Think of all the Linux Live CDs which need the CD inserted all the time, although **most** of the system is already in RAM.

If you can repartition your file system, you could install the "new" operation system in the second partition and mark that one as active and bootable.

1. Repartition file system for a second partiton (for the new OS)
2. Mark the new partition active and bootable
3. Format the new partition
4. Install the new OS (or a temporary one) in the second partition
5. Update bootloader (grub, LILO, ...) to boot from the new (second) partition
6. reboot
7. Delete contents of first partition
8. Install new OS into the first partition
9. Update bootloader (grub, LILO, ...) to boot from the first partition
10. reboot
11. Delete contents of second parition
12. Remove second partition
13. Resize first partition to full size

Resizing while running is difficult, but [this site](http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml) claims that it might be possible. It claimed (in 2007!) that he needed 2 GB of RAM for this operation...

Comment: Yea, this crossed my mind too, but I wonder if it's possible without all the re-partitioning. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I've update with a new idea (I mentioned that I'm intrigued, right?), this is tricky and should be done on a local device first to figured out the details. Especially as you want to ssh into the device after the first reboot.

Comment: Step 1 is probably the hardest - can you (safely) repartition an active filesystem?

Comment: @TobySpeight Safe is a relative term, but I think you can re-partition using pivot_root. At least I've seen people claiming it's doable.

Comment: HPC clusters often run without any disks on the compute nodes.  IF (big IF) you can get the system to boot over ethernet then you could prepare an image for it, boot diskless, work on the SD card and then reboot back to it.  I've only got a Pi2 and this wouldn't work because some firmware is loaded before boot, so I can't test for you.

Comment: If trying to resize, remember that XFS partitions cannot be shrunk, so if your root filesystem is XFS then shrinking and creating a new partition is a non-starter.